# Prove that a function is differentiable if...

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to prove that given a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^m$ in $p =(p_1, p_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, the function
$$ 
g(x, y) = f(x, y) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p)(x - p_1) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)(y - p_2) 
$$
is also differentiable in $(x, y) = p$?

Suppose that the partial derivatives in $p$ are $\neq 0$ and $f$ is once-differentiable.

What is the easiest and fastest way to prove it (using composition or linearity maybe)?

If works even if the domain of that function is $\mathbb{R}^n$ and
$$ g(\vec{x}) = f(\vec{x}) - \sum^n_{i = 1} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(p)(x_i - p_i)$$?

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ is once-differentiable, or has higher differentiability? If you're only assuming once-differentiable, then the statement isn't true, at least not as I read it. Also, when you write $\partial f / \partial x (x-p_1)$, at what point is the partial derivative being evaluated? At $p$? At $(x, y)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows, because you know the following

1. If $f,g:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $U\subset\mathbb{R}^{m}$
   open are differentiable in $p\in U$, then also $f+g$ is differentiable
   in $p$ (and the total derivative is given by $\left(D\left(f+g\right)\right)\left(p\right)=\left(Df\right)\left(p\right)+\left(Dg\right)\left(p\right)$).
   If you do not know that, you can use the definition of the total differential.
   For brevity, let us write $A:=\left(Df\right)\left(p\right)$ and
   $B:=\left(Dg\right)\left(p\right)$. Then
   $$
   \frac{\left|\left(f+g\right)\left(p+h\right)-\left(f+g\right)\left(p\right)-\left(A+B\right)\cdot h\right|}{\left\Vert h\right\Vert }\leq\frac{\left|f\left(p+h\right)-f\left(p\right)-A\cdot h\right|}{\left\Vert h\right\Vert }+\frac{\left|g\left(p+h\right)-g\left(p\right)-B\cdot h\right|}{\left\Vert h\right\Vert }\xrightarrow[h\rightarrow0]{}0.
   $$
2. A linear function $g:\mathbb{R}^{m}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable
   at every $p\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ with $\left(Dg\right)\left(p\right)=g$
   (here, we identify a linear functional with it's associated matrix).
   To see this, there are two ways. The first is to use again the definition
   of the total differential:
   $$
   \frac{\left|g\left(p+h\right)-g\left(p\right)-g\left(h\right)\right|}{\left\Vert h\right\Vert }=\frac{0}{\left\Vert h\right\Vert }\xrightarrow[h\rightarrow0]{}0.
   $$
   The second (if you are not that comfortable with the definition) is
   to use that there are $a_{1},\dots,a_{m}\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
   $g\left(x\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{i}x_{i}$ holds. You can then calculate
   the partial derivatives (verify this!)
   $$
   \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_{i}}\right)\left(x\right)=a_{i}
   $$
   for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$, so that the partial derivatives are
   constant, hence continuous. You can then use that a function which
   is continuously partially differentiable is also totally differentiable.

Finally, plug all this together: For the linear(!) map
$$
h:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},x\mapsto-\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}\left(p\right)\cdot x_{i}\right],
$$
your function $g$ is of the form
$$
g=f+h+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}\left(p\right)\cdot p_{i}\right],
$$
where the last term is constant(!), hence differentiable.

You can then even conclude that the total derivative of $g$ in $p$
vanishes.